# Transactions not working for my MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, transactions

I'm using a MySQL DB for my site, which is hosted on a Linux shared server.

I wrote a test script which I run using 'mysql' to test if transactions are working ok. Running the script, I do not get any error, but the result of executing the scripts is as if transaction is not enabled.

I also made sure to grant ALL privileges to the admin MySQL user which runs the script.

In order to double check, I tried the same test script on PostgreSQL, and there - the result of the script indicated that transaction does work. So it's definitely something which is specific to MySQL.

The script runs on a simple table which I created as follows:

```
create table a ( id serial primary key);
```

Following is the test script:

```
delete from a;
set autocommit = 0;
start transaction;
insert into a(id) values(1);
rollback work;
select count(*) from a;
```

So the script makes sure the table is empty, Then it starts a transaction, insert a row and rollback the insert. As the "insert" is rolled back, the "select" should indicate that table contains 0 rows.

Running this on PostgreSQL:

```
$ psql db admin < test1
DELETE 0
START TRANSACTION
INSERT 0 1
ROLLBACK
count
-------
     0
```

This is the expected behavior, 0 rows in the table as the insert was rolled back.

Running the same on my MySQL DB:

```
$ mysql db -u admin < test1
count(*)
1
```

Having 1 row following the rollback indicate that the "insert" was **not** rolled back, just as in non-transaction mode.

As mentioned, admin is granted with ALL privileges to the DB.

Anything I've missed?

Comment: Check on MySQL if the table engine is InnoDB... `SHOW CREATE TABLE A`

Comment: I dont see any commit before that select count in mysql.

Comment: I do not want to commit, I want to rollback :-) I'f I'll commit I will not know if transaction work or not. Rollback is a good indication that transaction works.

Comment: The engine name is MyISAM

Comment: @Ofer Lahav posted a answer how to fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the table is created with the MyISAM storage engine as default.
MyISAM storage engine doesnt support transactions.

**Create table**

```
CREATE TABLE a ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

**Query**

```
DELETE FROM a;
SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO a(id) VALUES(1);
ROLLBACK WORK;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a;
```

**Result**

### count(*)

```
     1
```

Making the table InnoDB

**Query**

```
ALTER TABLE a ENGINE=INNODB;
```

**Query**

```
DELETE FROM a;
SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO a(id) VALUES(1);
ROLLBACK WORK;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a;
```

**Result**

```
count(*)  
----------
         0
```

Comment: That is correct! Changed DB engine to InnoDB and not it works!!